# Full screen Dialog or a Modal Fragment

Tags: android

DialogFragment is displaying in a very small width and height window

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:name="components.Profile"
    android:label="Profile">

    <action android:id="@+id/action_profile_to_product" app:destination="@id/product" />
</fragment>

<dialog android:id="@+id/product" android:name="components.Product" android:label="Product"/>
```

Kotlin Class file is

```
class Product: DialogFragment() {

}
```

Fragment XML consists of a listView with checkboxes and Ok & Cancel buttons.

Before i used it as a fragment but it displays fine, now the requirement is to use it as a Dialog, also how to send the selection result back to the previous fragment?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/products"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cancel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ok"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancel" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

on iOS we have something like this.

[image]

Comment: I think I need something like this, a Modal Sheet but full screen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfpRL2K1hJk because I've a long list of products to choose from. Any lateral thinking?

Comment: I could have continued using product as a fragment but it causes cyclic between profile fragment and the product fragment

Comment: Your DialogFragment class is empty, it extends DialogFragment() but have you implemented the overridden methods and inflated your dialog, onCreateDialog() using AlertDialog.Builder(..). As for passing data you can create in interface that defines method for you button click and have the calling fragment implement it or have it defined as inline interface impl. in you class parameters

Comment: This tutorial might help : https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment#overview (java)

Comment: Yes, You need bottomsheetdialog as you say. You can show fullscreen.